# JavaScript: Stop a For loop with setTimeout function and this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically this pulls a list of visible links (some have display:none because of a filter that I've done prior) and clicks individually on each one with a time delay, as each link takes about 2 seconds to process. However, sometimes the link does not process and gives an error message. When this condition applies, I want to stop this process as it will only fill the server with requests where everyone returns an error. As I usually do, I already tried to create an `if (condition) { return; }`, but I was not very successful with this particular function.

```
    var x = 1,
        myVar = "",
        ModelA = true,
        VarOne = $('#axws a.icon_x').filter(":visible");

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (ModelA) {
            $(VarOne).eq(i).each(function() {

                    var timeNow = time * x;

                    setTimeout(function(myVar) {
                            $(myVar).click();
                    }, timeNow, this);
                ++x;
            });
        }
    }
```

Also, I just want to say that my javascript is not excellent, I learned it myself to automate some things that make my life easier (and I'm still learning). If anyone can help me and take the time to explain to me why it works that way, I'd be very grateful. I've been trying to find a solution for 4 hours and I couldn't get it to work. Thanks again.

**Edit:**

*In response to the first comments*, I already tried to use a `break`, but the `break` gives me an "Unsyntactic break" error. From what I understand from searching this forum, a `break` cannot be used with `.each` (I could be wrong).

I also tried with `return`, both `false` and `true` (just in case), but none of them worked, the loop catches the `console.log` I put before the `return`, but it doesn't stop the function.

I've also tried with an `if` `else`, so that it only clicks on the next one if it doesn't catch the condition, but the loop goes for the `if` (writing the console.log) and the `else` (clicking the link).

Unfortunately, it wasn't for lack of trying. I'm not really getting it.

**Edit 2: (Solved)**

I managed to solve it and I'll leave the answer here so that people who go through the same problem can solve it. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution to the problem here on the forum.

I think the problem with this was that I was using the `this` keyword which made the loop just being done in the `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function(myVar) {
    $(myVar).click();
}, timeNow, this);
```

Basically I redid the loop so I don't have to use the `this` keyword:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
} //New function to set a time out

var ModelA = true;   
var VarOne= $('#axws a.farm_icon_x').filter(":visible");

var nVarOne = $('#axws a.farm_icon_x').filter(":visible").length; //new var to set the exact i length to the exact number of links

        async function load () { // wrap loop into an async function for sleep to work
            for (let i = 0; i < nfarm; i++) {
                    
                if (ModelA) {
                    $(VarOne).eq(i).each(function() {
                        VarOne.eq(i).click();
                        console.log("Model A: " + i);
                    });
                }

                var time = (Math.random() * (5000 - 2000) + 2000).toFixed(0); //var to set sleep time
                await sleep(time); // then the created Promise can be awaited
            }
        }

        load(); //loop function
    }
```

That said, all that remains is to put the `condition` for the loop to stop `if { condition == true}`. As the loop will repeat the `for` and continue where the previous promise was, I just had to do, for example, this:

```
(...) if (ModelA && !condition) { ... }
```

Comment: When you return something in the function it is understood as completion of smt in the function scope. Use `break` to stop and `continue` to pass for the `for` loop.

Comment: @configtheworld I tried putting a `break`, but the `break` gives me an "Unsyntactic break" error. From what I understand from searching this forum, a `break` cannot be used with `.each`.

Comment: @code this is not a duplicate of the question that liked. Bruno, in the `for` loop you can add a condition to stop like `for (let i = 0; i < 5 && loopFlag !== true; i++)` [Check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-l9m81f?file=index.js)

Comment: @configtheworld have tried, but didn't work. Could this problem be because I'm using the `this` keyword to loop the `timeout` (adding 2 seconds between each click)? because what is looping over and over is just the timeout function that has the click. For each loop, only the code inside the timeout is read, at least I couldn't get a console.log to work after the first pass that creates the loop.

Comment: @code just solved the problem. Your `break` and Linked post couldn't help at all. Cuz was not the same problem. Thanks anyway.